# How to using String replace in velocity template (AWS appsync + elasticsearch)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, variadic-templates, aws-appsync

I'm writing a appsync query to search for records by phone number from elastic (using velocity template).

The data stored on the elastic has the form "0123456789" but the request may take the form "012-123-1234". So I intended to use the string replace function to remove "-" character. However, my code is returning the following error:

```
"message": "Lexical error, Encountered: \" _ \ "(95), after: \". \ "at * unset * [line 11, column 51]"
```

I am not sure if my writing is correct or not, please help.

This is my code:

```
{
    "version":"2017-02-28",
    "operation":"GET",
    "path":"/res/res/_search",
    "params":{
        "headers":{},
        "queryString":{},
        "body":{
            "from":$util.defaultIfNull($ctx.args.nextToken, 0),
            "size":$util.defaultIfNull($ctx.args.limit, 20),
            "query": {
                 "match": { "phoneNumber": "$context.args.phoneNumber".replace('-', '') }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well, I found the error, it's wrong position of " character.

```
"match": { "phoneNumber": "$context.args.phoneNumber".replace('-', '') }
```

=>

```
"match": { "phoneNumber": "$context.args.phoneNumber.replace('-', '')" }
```